# Does an IS-A relation needed for method overloading, or a HAS-A relationship is enough?

Tags: java

For method overloading there must be a IS-A relation ship. Is it correct? Or possible in case of HAS-A relationship?

Comment: Here are the [most trivial rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370), for the internet communication. Btw, HAS-A is not enough, you need IS-A.

Comment: "For method overloading there must be a IS-A relation ship" - between what? Please provide examples in code of what you're asking about. At the moment the question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are a bit confused with basic terminology. 
Overloading is defined like this:

> The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists

Read more at: [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Overloading has nothing to do with "is-a" or "has-a", it happens just in the class itself.

If your question is about overriding then you are talking about inheritance and this may be paraphrased with "is-a".

Read more at: [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)